# PowerBI Report Export in csv format via Rest API

Tags: api, powerbi, export, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

PowerBI provided CSV format export API for Paginated Reports alone, not for normal reports which support only pbix, ppt, png formats via Export API.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofile

Is there any API to export normal PowerBI reports in CSV format?

If not, is there any API to get the exact data present in a particular report?

Can you please help me with a solution/clarity on this since am looking for it for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no API to export Power BI report to CSV. When [designed properly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/modern-data-warehouse), this should be exported from the data source, which is used to build the Power BI report itself. There are still some options to do that, but you may not like them though.

First, you can use some [client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=azure-analysis-services-current) to connect to the dataset's [XMLA endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-connect-tools), but this requires Premium (announcement [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-open-platform-connectivity-with-xmla-endpoints-public-preview/) and for read/write [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-read-write-xmla-endpoints-in-power-bi-premium-public-preview/)).

The other options, like [Analyze in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel) and [exporting data from visualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data), has manual steps and bad [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data#limitations-and-considerations), which you may try to simulate, but I don't think this is a good solution.

As I conclusion, the best solution would be to make proper layers and avoid exporting data from the report layer at all.

Comment: Thank you Andrey. 
To confirm the solution, by using client Library, we can get the data from the datasource thats what you are refering right.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean.